# Arc theme wrong colors

Tags: themes, gnome-shell

I'm using Ubuntu 17.10. I installed Arc theme with `apt install arc-theme`. But if I use it calendar, and other drop-downs from Top Bar have wrong color.

[image]

Can I change color to match the other apps?
Is there an extension which can make it better looking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have changed the application theme to Arc, but not the shell theme.

Open Tweaks and choose Arc as the shell theme in the *Appearance* section.

[image]